# Notepad++ How to replace a with enter

Tags: notepad++, user-accounts, text-editors

I have a lot of accounts but they are stuck together like this:

```
username: password username: password....
```

I don't know how to make them into this:

```
Username: password
Username: password
```

I tried the replace but it doesn't extend to me, I typed find space bar replace it with /r and then extend /r

Comment: Your question is unanswerable unless you specify the list of (special) characters that are allowed in the username and password fields (particularly `:`)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can be more clear with your question, but to make from.

```
username: password username: password
```

To

```
username:
password
username:
password
```

You just do an Extended Find and Replace. Finding a `space` and replacing with `space` and `\r`. (now I see that you might've confused `\r` with `/r`. It is `\r`.)

See here in action:
[image]

Comment: That is a nice animation, what did you use to create it? The offset mouse pointer looks a bit strange. You could add apostrophes around the special control characters to make them stand out a bit in your answer.

Comment: I used ShareX (https://getsharex.com/) which is the best screenshot (and much more) tool I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

If the only defining structure is a number of characters followed by a colon followed by space and followed by another number of characters you could also potentially use the regular expression `(.*?: .*? )` (Notice the spaces!) in Notepad++ and replace it with `$1\r\n`. This would add a line break after each match. To open the replace dialog use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

The downside is that if either the username or password contains a colon it would break.

Answer (score -1):

Find: `([^\ ]*\ [^\ ]*)\`

Replace with: `\1\n`

Make sure you have enabled `Regular Expression`